# Target a specific word in body and apply a style to it?

Tags: jquery, cpu-word, target

Currently I am using a Jquery string to try and target a SPECIFIC word in the entire body of the site and add a class to it. So every single time the word "Nike" appears for example it will make it red and attach a TM to the end of it.

I have been using this but it only replaces the 1st occurrences of the work Nike in the content and I cannot figure out why its not replacing all of them.

Here is the sample: http://jsbin.com/ijufu3/21/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
$('body').html(
    function(i,h){
        return h.replace(/(Nike)/g,'<span class="nike tm">$1</span>');
    });​
```

Coupled with the following CSS:

```
.tm::after {
    content: '™';
}

.nike {
    color: red;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9yRGj/1/).

Where the selector is amended to whatever elements in which you expect to find the word.

Given that you may need to target browsers that don't implement the `::after` pseudo-elements/CSS-generated content, then there's also the option of:

```
$('body').html(
    function(i,h){
        return h.replace(/(Nike)/g,'<span class="nike">$1™</span>');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9yRGj/2/).

Which omits adding the `tm` class and explicitly adds that character to the HTML string returned.

These approaches work because regular expressions allow for the use of the `g` (I think 'global'?) flag, which replaces *every* occurence of the encountered match (the string within the parentheses). Because you're looking at the `html` content, though, this carries the risks that any class-name of `nike` will *itself* also be replaced, so be very, *very* sure that this string will *not* crop up in unexpected places (where the replacement would cause problems).

Comment: Works BEAUTIFULLY. You guys are geniuses. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Ran into a snag with this script that was working beautifully. So with the examples above it looks for "Nike" and applies a TM to the end of it. This became a problem when I created a link in my content for

It breaks the link and adds a TM to the end of Nike.

Is there a way I can specially eliminate that function from happening on this link? Perhaps adding some kind of invisible character in between a letter in Nike so it breaks from the function?

Comment: @crobley: I'd imagine so. Can you link me to a JS Fiddle showing representative HTML that you're currently working with?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `/Nike/g`

**.replace** will only do for the first occurrence.. To continue its search you need to do a global search..

```
$('p:contains(Nike)').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace(/Nike/g,'<span class="fancy">Nike</span>')
  );
});
```

​

Comment: Works BEAUTIFULLY. You guys are geniuses. Thanks so much :)

Comment: What seems to be the problem ..??